# react native flatlist height cannot automatically be changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a react native screen,  the top part is a flatlist,  and the bottom part is a toolbar, with some buttons in it.  And, there is also a hidden component which shows when a button is pressed.  What I hope is, when the hidden component is showing, the flatlist is pushed up,  so that lower part content of flatlist will be still on the screen.
But the reality is,  when the hidden component is showing,  it covers the flatlist.  I have no way to make flatlist component automatically be smaller.

How to resolve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Does your FlatList have absolute positioning? Can you post the code?

Comment: Can you share the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try styling all three component using `flex`.

for e.g.

give flatlist `flex:3`

hidden button `flex:1`

toolbar `flex:2`

And now when button appears, height will be automatically adjusted.